# Liquibase Java API DBMS Mismatch

Tags: mysql, liquibase

I'm trying to integrate Liquibase into a Java Spring application to manage databases based on a connection string passed in from other locations in my application stack. Basically I've got the update scripts and connection strings managed elsewhere and I'm just working building an application to execute the Liquibase updates.

The issue I'm running into is that all my changesets are simply getting skipped. I'm outputting as much from the Liquibase results as I can find in the Java documentation for the Liquibase library, but all I'm seeing that might be an error is the following:

`DBMS mismatch (dbmsMismatch): Database 'mysql' matches all databases`

I can't find anything about this in the Liquibase documentation anywhere.

The output from the `liquibase.update()` updateWriter is the following:

```
1 changesets have not been applied to <username>@<hostname>@jdbc:mysql:@<hostname>:<port>/<db_name>
     v1.03__scheduler_test_updates.sql::3::author
```

This correctly references the changeset that I expect to be run, but doesn't give me any information as to why it has not been applied.

The best part, is that I have a different version of the application using a much older version of Java Spring and Liquibase that works just fine. I'm attempting to upgrade everything to newer versions because I need to add much more robust logging and notifications before this can be ready for a production environment.

I've included the full content of the changeset file here:

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset author:1 labels:ad_hoc__testing
ALTER TABLE `test-new-table` ADD COLUMN `isManager` tinyint(1) DEFAULT 0;

--changeset author:2 labels:ad_hoc__testing
INSERT INTO `test-new-table` (`name`, `description`) VALUES ("First Entry", "This is the first entry in the table.");

--changeset author:3 labels:ad_hoc__testing
INSERT INTO `test-new-table` (`name`, `description`, `isManager`) VALUES ("Second Entry", "This is the second entry in the table.", 1);
```

Comment: What does the changeset "v1.03__scheduler_test_updates.sql" look like? Does it include a "dbms" attribute? For all attributes, see: https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/attributes/home.html

Comment: I updated the question to include the full contents of the changeset file. There are no "DBMD" attributes in the file.